# New users answering a string of questions within a particular time frame and vanishes. Is it good?

Tags: discussion

I am noticing an eerie pattern in the home page. Some new users(registered for couple of days, some are unregistered) answers a string of questions within a particular time frame (say 1 hour), then vanishes. They come after some days to answer questions (usually in bursts), others don't come at all. The answers are particularly of 3-4 lines with no references whatsoever (most of them are opinion based answers). Is it good? How to deal with such users? How to handle such situation?

Note: I haven't named any users and do not have any ill-intentions towards them. I am not targeting any user for such activity. I am just shedding some light on this situation and seek appropriate measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this not good. However it is a part of the platform, especially since there is virtually no barrier of entry. Anybody is free to ask and/or answer questions, and most people will come to this platform with a typical forum/comment mindset. Just dropping their 2 cents where they can and want, and moving on.

This is not just a mindset limited to answers either. Often referred to as [help vampires](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1193/1458) are also often found on the platform. Users that ask a question, never to return after. Or in some cases dissapear after a few days at most.

The best thing we can do is guide these users in the ways of stack exchange by guiding them to the [tour] or [help-center]. Provide them with a short pointer on why we work/prefer to do it different on this platform. And perhaps some instructions on how they could improve their answers and/or questions.

Personally I like the approach [Madara's ghost](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/438/1458) mentions:

> Be gracious, be professional. Don't drive away users. Be patient towards them, explain their mistakes, refer them to the FAQ and /about page if necessary.

> If you aren't sure, flag it for moderator attention and we'll handle it.

> In general, don't be trigger happy with downvotes, prefer comments and communication.

> Downvotes are reserved for posts which aren't helpful, badly formatted or aren't clear.