# Deprecating "Questions about making your own anime/manga" in favor of "Questions about anime/manga recommendations" close reasons

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, off-topic

I've noticed we're getting more and more of these questions.

> I've seen anime X and really liked it! What similar animes are there for me to watch?

or

> I'm looking for an anime about Y to watch, any suggestions?

or

> What anime should I watch next? I'm bored and I like the Z genre.

So I think it's just about time we give it its own off-topic close reason, because apparently "primarily opinion based" just doesn't cut it.

#### So we're deprecating the very rarely used "Questions about making your own anime/manga" in favor of "Questions about recommendations".

The following phrasing is proposed:

> Questions about **watching or reading recommendations** are off-topic
>   because they tend to attract opinionated answers and clutter.  For
>   more information, see [Should we allow recommendation
>   questions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117)

This transition will happen in approximately a week, to let people voice their opinions/objections/suggestions/comments. This is the place to do it.

Answer this question with anything you've got, that includes, but not limited to:

- Suggesting alternative phrasing.
- Suggesting a different meta post to link.
- Objections (With actual arguments please)
- Comments regarding the deprecation of the "Questions about making your own anime/manga" reason.

Please voice your opinions!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). The following phrasing was adopted and is now live.**

I support this as questions about making anime and manga have become few compared to recommendation questions. While "primarily opinion-based" is *technically* correct, I feel like it doesn't highlight well enough exactly what is opinion-based about the question. Many people coming to the site do not necessarily have experience with the Stack Exchange Q&A mentality.

I'll reiterate earlier comments I made:

- I think the "clutter" part of the close reason might not be the best, and particularly wouldn't mean anything to those asking these questions. Perhaps something like:

  > "Questions about **watching or reading recommendations** are off-topic because they tend to attract discussion and opinionated answers. For more information, see [Should we allow recommendation questions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117)
- The only issue I take with the meta post is that the answer is not accepted, but this is not a critical issue.

And since I feel like this message is too short, [here is an image of an anime character approving this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMCAq.png).