# New users asking about Anime Recommendations

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

I have noticed that the first thing a new user does on this site is...

> Asks a question about recommendations on what anime to watch next and vice versa.

I think we need to make this more clear on Anime and Manga.SE. We should clearly state in the tour not to ask questions such as this. But this is where we come to problem number 2...

> Almost every new users does not read the **Tour** section of our website

So what would be the recommended action for this? Also when flagging questions like this what should I flag it as?

Off-Topic or Opinion Based. Both these options however don't exactly sound right though. Should we make a new option in/under "It should be closed for other reasons"?

Comment: Besides what @Eric said in the answer below, it is actually clearly specified in the tour page that recommendation questions are not allowed.

Comment: Im pretty sure when I looked it wasn't there, thanks though. I might need some glasses. XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We [recently created an off-topic close reason for anime recommendations](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/887/274).

> Questions about **watching or reading recommendations** are off-topic because they tend to attract discussion and opinionated answers. For more information, see [Should we allow recommendation questions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117)

Such as on [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/8553/274), this is the reason that should be used to close questions like these. (To be clear: **Users with 500+ reputation should be [casting close votes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), *not flagging it.***)