# Inviting users seeking recommendations to chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, off-topic, chat

I've a suggestion.

We currently have the recommendation close reason:

> Questions about **watching or reading recommendations** are off-topic
>   because they tend to attract opinionated answers and clutter.  For
>   more information, see [Should we allow recommendation
>   questions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117)

I propose that we add an invitation to chat in that close reason:

> Questions about **watching or reading recommendations** are off-topic
>   because they tend to attract opinionated answers and clutter.  For
>   more information, see [Should we allow recommendation
>   questions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117) If
>   you'd like, you can ask for recommendations in **[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/)**.

Or some similar wording.

What do you think?

Comment: The only problem I see with your current wording is that many of the users who ask these questions are 1-rep users who can't chat (unless a moderator gives them write access). I usually refrain from mentioning chat to these users or write something of the form "once you have the required 20 reputation, you can ask in chat".

Answer (score 8):

Overall, I'm in favor of such a change, but I suggest that we make it explicit that 20 reputation is needed to talk in chat. Otherwise, we run the risk of being even more off-putting to new users who want recommendations. Hence, I suggest we modify the wording a bit to take this into account. Here's my own (slightly awkward) attempt:

> Questions about **watching or reading recommendations** are off-topic because they tend to attract opinionated answers and clutter. For more information, see [Should we allow recommendation questions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117) If you have [enough reputation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), you're welcome to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-).

Comment: It's like to impose a quick change in wording, "If" -> "When," this way, to a new user, in won't seem like we're imposing a limit to low rep users, but rather encourage them to get more rep so they can participate.

Comment: @Krazer I considered that. "If" is undesirable for the reasons you state. On the other hand "When" (and "Once" and every other option I could think of) reads somewhat awkwardly for users who already have 20 rep. With that said, I'm not attached to this wording at all, so if you think that's an improvement then go ahead and change it.

Comment: How about, "After earning enough reputation, you're welcome to ask in chat."? It's slightly less awkward to those who have achieved it already, I think.

Comment: Maybe something like "More information on [how to increase your reputation]()" should be added at the end too. People who don't know about the reputation requirement to get into the chat, might not even know how the reputation system works at all.