# Should we have a tag that most likely result in the question being closed?

Tags: feature-request, tags, close-reasons

I realise the phrasing for this is a little odd, so I'll elaborate. The one tag I'm thinking of would be "recommendations".
Currently recommendation questions are not allowed under our [consensus](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/should-we-allow-recommendation-questions). But are still popping up from time to time. They are also mistagged as [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request), [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production), [resources](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources), etc.

My questions is therefore, is such a tag like [recommendations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) a good idea? And there could be a similar popup like for id-requests, pointing users to the meta post describing how it isn't answered by our SE.

My idea is that such questions should be retagged as such and closed, or if the user asks and tags correctly, they will be pointed to the correct places.

Comment: ^ IMO my reasoning there still applies, but if there's interest in revisiting the issue, we can discuss this again